# System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Meal_Plan'.'2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to run an MVC app but it shows the following error:

When it runs it shows table information from Faculty Table, but when I click on Add new, it shows the next error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Meal_Plan'.'


System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Meal_Plan'.
  Source=System.Web.Mvc
  StackTrace:
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.GetSelectData(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String name)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Object htmlAttributes)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Faculty_Guardar_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\josem\Desktop\Code POS\POS\POS\Views\Faculty\Guardar.cshtml:line /at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

```html
@model POS.Models.Faculty

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Guardar";
}

<h2>Guardar</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Nuevo","Producto",FormMethod.Post)) //Metodo "Nuevo", Controlador "Producto", Accion "HTTP POST"
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Faculty</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Organization_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Organization_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Organization_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Job_Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Job_Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job_Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Meal_Plan, "Meal_Plan", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Meal_Plan", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Meal_Plan, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Meal_Plan_Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Meal_Plan_Status)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Meal_Plan_Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <font color="green">@ViewBag.mensaje</font>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: They problem is in these lines: 

    <div class="form-group">
            Html.LabelFor(model => model.Meal_Plan, "Meal_Plan", htmlAttributes: new { class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                **Html.DropDownList("Meal_Plan", null, htmlAttributes: new { class = "form-control" })**
                Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Meal_Plan, "", new { class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Please edit your question if you have more information. The comment section is for comments like this

Comment: @Mythellaneous ok, but what was exactly the problem...?

Answer (score 0):

The overload of HtmlHelper.DropdownList that you're using requires the options for the dropdown to be placed in ViewData, with a key that has the **same name** as the dropdown, i.e. "Meal_Plan". In your controller you need to create the list items and then store them in ViewData (or store them in the model and use a different overload).

```
List<SelectListItem> mealPlanOptions = ...;
ViewData["Meal_Plan"] = mealPlanOptions;
```